# Math.max not returning either number being compared

Tags: javascript, math

Below is a simply `Math.max` statement I'm trying to use in my jQuery app, along with the methods being called.

```
    guaranteedEoy: function() {
        return this.fixedAllocation() * (1 + (this.attributes.fixedRate / 100)) * Math.pow(1, 6);
    },

    contractVal: function (value) {
        value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.guaranteedEoy());
        console.log(parseFloat(this.guaranteedEoy()) + parseFloat(value));
        console.log(this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7));
        console.log(Math.max((this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7)), (this.guaranteedEoy() + value)));
        console.log('   ');
        return Math.max((this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7)), (this.guaranteedEoy() + value));
    },
```

I put the `console.log` statements in there because the number being returned from the `Math.max` function is exponentially larger than either number it is supposed to be comparing. To illustrate here's a screen print of the console readouts from above:

[image]

To simplify here are the values each console readout correspond to

```
Value: 64000.00
this.guaranteedEoy(): 37008
this.guaranteedEoy() + value: 101008
this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7): 107213.53521070098
Math.max((this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7)), (this.guaranteedEoy() + value)): 370086400
```

So basically the `Math.max` statement reads

```
Math.max(107213.53521070098, 101008)
```

However for some reason it is returning a value of `370086400`.

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string. Why are you even using it? Do you just want to round the value?

Comment: This question does not seem to have anything to do with jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`370086400` is concatenation of mentioned values `37008` and `64000`.

It should be:

```
console.log(Math.max((this.attributes.purchasePayment * Math.pow(1.01, 7)),
        (parseFloat(this.guaranteedEoy()) + parseFloat(value))));
```

Use `parseFloat` once more to avoid string concatenation (which is occured).

**Edit**: it looks like `value` is the String (due to `.toFixed()`), while `this.guaranteedEoy()` returns Number. So it is possible that `parseFloat` only for `value` will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed` returns a string, so `this.guaranteedEoy() + value`, performs *string concatenation*. If you just want to round the value to two decimal places, see [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11832914/218196).